# xstream is not parsing root element

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xstream

I am using `'com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:1.4.10'` library and trying to parse xml files.

Broker is the root element and there are other tags inside

```
<broker>
   <othertags/>
</broker>
```

The problem is when I am generating an xml file it is generating properly but it is not able read a file.

```
@XStreamAlias("broker")
public static class Broker {
```

While file generation it is able to convert Broker class to  but not the other way around. All other classes and list are getting correctly mapped but the root `@XStreamAlias` is not working while reading.

Any pointers as to why will be very helpful.

The exception I am getting:
`com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: broker`

One more question: while calling xStream.fromXML(responseString) how does xStream know which class to use? Say I have two classes with same alias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XStream does not process annotations by default.
Add the following before the deserialization of your xml content.

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();
xstream.processAnnotations(Broker.class);
```

Comment: I am actually using the auto detect `xStream.autodetectAnnotations(true);`

Comment: while calling xStream.fromXML(responseString) how does xStream know which class to use? Say I have two classes with same alias

Comment: Autodetect can only work for serialization. When deserializing, you need to specify XStream how to handle each types. Here is an extract from the official documentation: "Therefore it is no problem to serialize an object graph into XML, since XStream will know of all types in advance. `This is no longer true at deserialization time. XStream has to know the alias to turn it into the proper type`, but it can find the annotation for the alias only if it has processed the type in advance."

Comment: About sharing the same alias, it does not seem a good practice: see https://github.com/x-stream/xstream/issues/102 .